# Azure Active Directory Restricted Guest User Account With Specific Member User Permissions

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

Inside of Azure AD I have 10 restricted guest user accounts. I want to allow those guest users to invite guests, and add guests to groups that they own. Those permissions however are limited to member users. Is there any way for me to grant them a "custom" permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first permission, you can give them the Guest Inviter role. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/delegate-invitations

There is an open feedback request to be able to delegate group management (microsoft.directory/groups/members/update). Right now this does require User Admin, Group Admin, or Global Admin permissions. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/12868950-rbac-for-aad